# Creating an instance of an array of objects class in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, initialization, instance

I'm new to Java, and I'm getting an error in my main function when I try to create an instance of a DeckofCards class.  The DeckofCards class is supposed to be a private array of "Cards" objects.  I think my issue is something in the DeckofCards class, for some reason it's not an array I think? Maybe I created it wrong?

The errors in my main are 
**'(' or '[' expected**
and
**array required but DeckofCards found**

Here is my main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Card myCard = new Card(13,1);
        System.out.println(myCard.getSuit());
        System.out.println(myCard);
        DeckofCards myDeck = new DeckofCards;  //error here
        for(int i=0; i<53; i++) {
            System.out.println(myDeck[i]); //second error here
        }
    }
```

Here is my DeckofCards class:

```
public class DeckofCards {

    private Card[] deck = new Card[52];

    public DeckofCards(){
        int i = 0;

            for(int s = 1; s<5; s++){
                for(int r = 1; r<14; r++){
            deck[i].rank = r;
            deck[i].suit = s;
            i++;

    }
}
    }
}
```

If anyone can tell me if I'm missing some syntax or something that'd be great!  Thank you.

Comment: "for some reason it's not an array I think" - Well you just about hit the nail on the head. Use methods to interact with the `Card` array in your deck class.

Comment: Instead of `new DeckofCards` use `new DeckofCards()`

Comment: Note: to construct an object (or actually set its parameters) you need to call a constructor. A constructor is a method of your class (even if you do not write your own constructor explicitely, Java will provide a default constructor for the class.) Now you actually wrote your constructor (`public DeckOfCards()`) in your class, and see: it is a method. To call a method in Java you need to type `methodName(arguments)`. The parentheses are obligatory and arguments are not (for example, the constructor you wrote takes no arguments).

Comment: Can someone explain why System.out.println(myDeck[i]) returns an error?  System.out.println(myCard) returns the card ("Ace of Spades" for example) and isn't myDeck[i] just a card?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call the constructor:

```
DeckofCards myDeck = new DeckofCards(); // note parens!
```

In Java, the parentheses are required.

In the constructor, you will also need to initialize each element of the array to a new `Card` object:

```
for(int s = 1; s<5; s++){
    for(int r = 1; r<14; r++){
        deck[i] = new Card();
        deck[i].rank = r;
        deck[i].suit = s;
        i++;
```

Comment: Thanks Ted! Can you also explain why System.out.println(myDeck[i]) returns an error? println(myCard) prints out the card value ('Four of Clubs") so shouldn't that last for loop print out the values of all the cards?

Comment: @Acoustic77 - The variable `myDeck` is not an array, so you can't access parts of it using array subscripting. If you want to print the i-th card in the deck, you'll need a getter method in `DeckofCards` (for instance: `public Card getCard(int i) { return deck[i]; }`). Then you could try `System.out.println(myDeck.get(i));`.

Answer (score 3):

The error is pretty clear, `myDeck` is a single custom `Object` rather than an array

```
DeckofCards myDeck = new DeckofCards();  // parenthesis here
for (int i=0; i<53; i++) {
    System.out.println(myDeck); // no brackets here
}
```

Although the loop itself should be located within the `toString` method of the `DeckofCards` class.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
DeckofCards myDeck = new DeckofCards;
```

with

```
DeckofCards myDeck = new DeckofCards();
```

and `myDeck` was never initialized to be an array.

Answer (score 1):

In order to iterate through the DeckofCards  you'll want to expose that private Card[] array.  You can use the bean notation getCards() or just make the array public.

```
    public class DeckofCards {

        private Card[] deck = new Card[52];

        public DeckofCards(){
            int i = 0;

                for(int s = 1; s<5; s++){
                    for(int r = 1; r<14; r++){
                deck[i].rank = r;
                deck[i].suit = s;
                i++;

        }
      } 
    }
     public Card[] getCards(){

          return deck;

     }
   }
```

I would probably just make the deck public.